# Starting to use Subversion in Android Studio

Tags: android, svn, android-studio

I have a few projects developed in Eclipse, then migrated into Android Studio.  To simplify development on multiple computers, I would like to use SVN.  The server has been set up with an empty repository; I have also installed the TortoiseSVN client.  I turned on version control in Android Studio and set the path to SVN.  Now what?  If I click on the src folder in the project and go into Subversion-Add, I get "Not a working copy".  Obviously, I don't want to version control auto-generated files created by Android Studio, so I can't "import" the entire project directory...

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you have to right click a project and select 'Team - Share Project...' and use the wizard. This will only version the root folder of your project. Then you can add all the elements you want to add to the repository and define ignore properties for elements you don't want to version.